# Android: align relative layout to center

Tags: android

Going crazy to tryng align entire relative layout to the center of the screen.

This is the dashboard_fragment that I need to align:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter_day"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/next_event_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/counter_day"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/last_event_placeholder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/counter_day"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/next_event_placeholder"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="My Application" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It's a fragment, injected inside base_layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!--
        IF YOU NEED HEADER:
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is a very basic layout that I would:

[image]

But at the moment my layout is on the top-left of the screen.

Thank you very much.

Comment: problem is in First xml or in 2nd?

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_gravity="center"` on the RelativeLayout, or  `android:gravity="center"` on the FrameLayout (or both).

Comment: I don't want edit the FrameLayout, because I use for others views. If I add the android:layout_gravity="center" my layout is aligned to center vertically but left horizontally

Comment: Try changing its width from fill_parent to match_parent .

Comment: It doesn't work. Relative layout is center but to the left

Answer (score 0):

Modify like this:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/counter_day"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/next_event_placeholder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/counter_day"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/last_event_placeholder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/counter_day"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/next_event_placeholder"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="My Application" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

only you have to put gravity for Relative layout.

Comment: With the layout_gravity: center it center template vertically, but it's aligned to left....

Comment: make width of TextView wrap content, if you can't then set gravity for textView also.